# Rails virtual attribute array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, simple-form

I am creating a virtual attribute in my model:

```
def entities
  @entities = Array.new()
  @entities.push(self.contact.name)
  @entities.push(self.contact.partner.name) if self.contact.partner
  @entities.push('Joint') if self.contact.partner
  @entities
end
```

Then in my form I'm trying to use this array from a nested array. I'm using simple form so it looks like this

```
<%= f.input :ownership, collection: :entities, :include_blank => false, :label => false %>
```

However this gives me an error:

```
undefined method `to_a' for :entities:Symbol
```

If I have created an array, I don't understand why it isn't rendering as an array. What am I missing?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens when you output @entities on your page? You get a nice array as expected?

Comment: Didn't try cause I got an answer below. Guessing I would have to output @object.entities to get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `:entities` as the collection:

```
<%= f.input :ownership, collection: :entities ...%>
```

That doesn't work. The error indicates that Simple Form is attempting to convert the argument `:entities` to an array, which is causing an error.

You need to give it an actual collection:

```
<%= f.input :ownership, collection: @object.entities ... %>
```